# concurrent NSOperation, why start on main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am studying this source code which demonstrates how to use NSURLConnection with NSOperation:
[link](https://github.com/alphonsolabs/Operations-Demo/blob/master/OperationsDemo/DownloadUrlOperation.m)

I am confused about the code at line `76`

```
if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start)
                               withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
```

Why is the author making sure that the code is run on main thread?

Isn't the whole point of NSOperation to not run on main thread and in a background thread so that it doesn't block?

The code is from this article that explains it although it doesn't answer my questions: http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/

Comment: It's kind of hard to guess with just this one snippet with no context...

Comment: Not sure why. NSURLConnection will function on a background thread just fine.

Comment: @Paul.s there's a link to all the code: https://github.com/alphonsolabs/Operations-Demo/blob/master/OperationsDemo/DownloadUrlOperation.m

Answer (score 1):

From the [NSURLConnection docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can see;

> NSURLConnection’s delegate methods—defined by the NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol protocol—allow an object to receive informational callbacks about the asynchronous load of a URL request. [...] **These delegate methods are called on the thread that started the asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLConnection object.**

Starting an operation on an NSURLConnection works on any thread, however it's very useful to get the delegate callbacks on the GUI/main thread if you want to - for example - display progress.

Comment: Absolutely. I think the confusion was maybe that it was calling start on itself? is this where the confusion arose?

Comment: I am sorry but this has nothing to do with the UI (even though I understand your point). Please check my answer (I found out after a bit of research).

Answer (score 0):

If you use NSURLConnection asynchronous you need to launch this operation on Main Thread for getting the callback. If you launch an asynchronous NSURLConnection from a background thread you can lose it callback if your background thread from you launched your NSURLConnection is busy for other activity.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer further? This seems more like a comment. Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

If you call start method in main thread, A current operation main method will be run in main thread, but you push current operation to NSOperationQueue（not main queue), start method call in sub thread, a current operation main method in sub thread.

[Sub Thread Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itGHV.png)

[Main Method in Sub Thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Koc.png)

Answer (score -1):

If this is an example I believe that this is put into there in order for you to see the difference between having that code in there and not. If this code were to be executing concurrently and is supposed to leave your main thread alive then indeed that section of code should not be there however it may have been put in there for you to remove and see the difference. However you are indeed correct. Browsing through the rest of the file it looks like that should not be in there if you are wanting to leave your main thread open.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got to the code from this aticle: http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/

Answer (score -1):

The reason is, on iOS 4.0+, wether the operation is concurrent or not, the operation is ran in a background thread. Since in this case the operation is concurrent, the method exists immediately and the thread is killed so no delegate method is called (NSURLConnection calls delegate method on the thread from which it started).

The only options are, either to start an NSRunLoop (very hectic) or use a thread that already has one (main thread) - so that's why the start method is run from the main thread.

Has nothing to do with updating UI as many suggested (although i understand the point but the entire reason to run an NSURLConnection in a queue is to process the delegate callbacks in a seperate thread to avoid blocking UI). That wasn't the intention of the author, the fact that it is UIKit safe is a mere consequence.